# ¿Porqué me sale este error? Severidad: Advertencia Mensaje: array_merge (): El argumento # 1 no es una matriz

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente código:

> Severity: Warning 
>   Message: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

```
<?php $this->load->view('formats/attachments/data-sheet', array_merge($result_det_ficha[0], $result_pre[0])); ?>
```

En ese data-sheet se encuentra la Ficha que cargue:

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('rol') === "3"): ?>
    <?php if ($this->session->userdata('name') === $usuario): ?>
        <p class="col-xs-4">
            <label> Ficha Técnica </label>
            <input type="file" name="archivo_ficha_tecnica" />
        </p>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <label> Adjunto </label>
            <?php if (isset($archivo)): ?>
                <a href="<?= base_url('file/downloads/') . $archivo . '/' . $tipoArchivo; ?>" target="_blank">Descargar / Ver</a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span title="Sin archivo adjunto">Sin archivo adjuntado</span>
            <?php endif; ?><br>
        </div>
        <p class="col-xs-4">
            <label> Estatus </label>
            <?php if ($estatusFicha === 'En Trámite'): ?>
                <?= form_dropdown('efichatecnica', array('En Trámite' => 'En Trámite', 'Rechazado' => 'Rechazado', 'Aprobado' => 'Aprobado'), $estatusFicha, array('class' => 'form-control text')) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php
                $clase = array(
                    'class' => 'form-control text',
                    'readonly' => 'readonly'
                );

                if ($estatusFicha === 'Aprobado') {
                    $clase['class'].=' verde';
                } elseif ($estatusFicha === 'Rechazado') {
                    $clase['class'].=' rojo';
                }
                ?>
                <?= form_input(array('name' => 'efichatecnica', 'placeholder' => 'Estatus'), $estatusFicha, $clase) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label> Ficha Técnica </label>
            <?php if (isset($archivo)): ?>
                <a href="<?= base_url('file/downloads/') . $archivo . '/' . $tipoArchivo; ?>" target="_blank">Descargar / Ver</a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span title="Sin archivo adjunto">Sin archivo adjuntado</span>
            <?php endif; ?><br>
        </div>
        <p class="col-xs-6">
            <label> Estatus </label>
            <?php if ($estatusFicha === 'En Trámite'): ?>
                <?= form_dropdown('efichatecnica', array('En Trámite' => 'En Trámite', 'Rechazado' => 'Rechazado', 'Aprobado' => 'Aprobado'), $estatusFicha, array('class' => 'form-control text')) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php
                $clase = array(
                    'class' => 'form-control text',
                    'readonly' => 'readonly'
                );

                if ($estatusFicha === 'Aprobado') {
                    $clase['class'].=' verde';
                } elseif ($estatusFicha === 'Rechazado') {
                    $clase['class'].=' rojo';
                }
                ?>
                <?= form_input(array('name' => 'efichatecnica', 'placeholder' => 'Estatus'), $estatusFicha, $clase) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p id="error_observacion" class="col-xs-12 text-center hidden">
        <?= 'Debe ingresar motivo de rechazo en el campo de observaciones'; ?>
    </p>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if ($estatusFicha !== "Aprobado") { ?>
        <p class="col-xs-4">
            <label> Ficha Técnica </label>
            <input type="file" name="archivo_ficha_tecnica" />
        </p>
        <p class="col-xs-4">
            <label> Adjunto </label>
            <?php if (isset($archivo)): ?>
                <a href="<?= base_url('file/downloads/') . $archivo . '/' . $tipoArchivo; ?>" target="_blank">Descargar / Ver</a>
            <?php else: ?>
                <span title="Sin archivo adjunto">Sin archivo adjuntado</span>
            <?php endif; ?><br>
        </p>
        <p class="col-xs-4">
        <?php } else { ?>
        <p class="col-xs-6">
            <label> Ficha Técnica </label>
            <input type="file" name="archivo_ficha_tecnica" />
        </p>
        <p class="col-xs-6">
        <?php } ?>
        <label> Estatus </label>
        <?php
        $clase = array(
            'class' => 'form-control text',
            'readonly' => 'readonly'
        );

        if ($estatusFicha === 'Aprobado') {
            $clase['class'].=' verde';
        } elseif ($estatusFicha === 'Rechazado') {
            $clase['class'].=' rojo';
        }
        ?>
        <?= form_input(array('name' => 'efichatecnica', 'placeholder' => 'Estatus'), $estatusFicha, $clase) ?>
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>
<p class="col-xs-12">
    <label> Observación </label>
    <?php if ($this->session->userdata('rol') === '3'): ?>
        <?php if ($estatusFicha === 'En Trámite'): ?>
            <?= form_textarea(array('name' => 'ofichatecnica', 'placeholder' => 'Observaciones'), $obsFicha, array('class' => 'form-control text', 'style' => 'resize: none;')) ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?= form_textarea(array('name' => 'ofichatecnica', 'placeholder' => 'Observaciones'), $obsFicha, array('class' => 'form-control text', 'style' => 'resize: none;', 'readonly' => 'readonly')) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?= form_textarea(array('name' => 'ofichatecnica', 'placeholder' => 'Observaciones'), $obsFicha, array('class' => 'form-control text', 'style' => 'resize: none;', 'readonly' => 'readonly')) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: Te está diciendo que '$result_det_ficha' no es un array y no puede coger la posición 0, haz un var_dump de la variable a ver que información te da.

Comment: Porque array_merge recibe arreglos de parámetros. Y según puedo apreciar a simple vista no le estás pasando arreglos, le estás pasando el valor del index de un arreglo (al menos que array_merg sea un arreglo de arreglos...) Así que pásale simplemente el arreglo a la función, sin el index ps.

Comment: Me sale lo siguiente: array(20) { [0]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(3) "105" ["obsUsuario"]=> NULL ["idArchivo"]=> string(3) "422" ["archivo"]=> NULL ["directorioArchivo"]=> NULL ["tipoArchivo"]=> string(5) "Ficha" ["idFicha"]=> string(2) "62" ["obsFicha"]=> string(0) "" ["estatusFicha"]=> string(11) "En Trámite" ["fechaFicha"]=> NULL ["estatusCargaF"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> array(11) { ["id"]=> string(3) "105" ["obsUsuario"]=> NULL ["idArchivo"]=> string(3) "430" ["archivo"]=> NULL ["directorioArchivo"]=> NULL ["tipoArchivo"]=> string(5) "Ficha" ["idFicha"]=> string(2) "63"...

Comment: pero si el var_dump es para $result_pre, me sale Null es todo

Comment: Como dice user2930137 array_merge recibe arrays para unirlos, quita la referencia al primer elemento [0] en los arrays dentro de la función array_merge

Comment: le quite el primer argumento y aun sigue el mismo array y el mismo comentario

Comment: No había visto que el segundo array es nulo, puede ser un problema, puedes pasar tantos arrays como quieras pero no deberían ser nulos.

Comment: esas dos variables son las siguientes: estan en la misma página: form_hidden('etiquetaEstatus', $result_pre[0]['etiqueta']);
form_hidden('idFicha', $result_det_ficha[0]['idFicha']);